# How to treat <option> value in PHP to be readable inside a DB

Tags: php, mysql, forms

So I have a long list of Universities in my country which have very long names and I need to assign a value to each `<option value="1">LONG NAME </option>` tag. The thing is that the value is numeric and I want it to be readable when I return the data from my database.

Long story short the code below returns my value numeric. How do I translate it into the name of the University?

```
<form method="post" action=""">
  <select name="university">
    <option value="1">UNIVERSITY LONG NAME </option>
    <option value="2">UNIVERSITY LONG NAME....</option>
    <option value="3">UNIVERSITY LONG NAME 2</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit the form"/>
</form>

<?php
 $option = isset($_POST['university']) ? $_POST['university'] : false;
   if ($option) {
      echo htmlentities($_POST['university'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
   } else {
     echo "task option is required";
     exit; 
   }
?>
```

Comment: You would need a storage array (assembled from a json file, xml, or database table [probably best depending on how many you have]) that has the key as the numeric and the value as the proper name: `$uni = array(0=>"Long Name University"); echo $uni[0];`

Comment: you should probably store the id's and have another table for id to name relationship. but its a guess not knowing the full scope here. Otherwise just put the name as the value, it can be text, its not restricted to being a number

Comment: How did you generate the form? Use the same code to get the university name from its ID.

Comment: Flow: Chose your university->POST it to DB->Return IT on another front-end

Comment: You could replace all spaces with `_`, or create table for all universities you have, then output the id as value and name as UI. You can retrieve the chosen university through `SELECT 'name' FROM universities WHERE 'id' = '2'` Make use of relational databases :)!

Comment: @AdamAzad Good idea. I`m just a bit blocked on they way I treat the flow of information

Comment: @Daniel, how so? The flow you posted seems to work fine with what I suggested.

Comment: Query `SELECT name, id FROM universities`, fetch it, then output the information in `option` element. `value` is the `id`, `name` is the content.

Comment: @chris85 Firstly I need to store it with the name when the user submits it

Comment: Instead of `action="""` (separate note but too many quotes there) send it to a processing script then send the name back in a `GET` parameter, `SESSION` value, or `COOKIE` value.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need a database that has universities details so you can fetch them or show them to the end user depends on what university he pick .
 I created a table called *universities* and add 2 fields ( ID , university_name) , the id field will be a primary key for the table , every university will have a unique id , no way that two universities can have the same id , so when the uesr pick a university the code will search for that university depends on its id .

Just to test the code i added 3 universities , this this is the table structure and the universities that i added to it :

Table Structure :

[image]

Universities that i added for this test :

- University of Alaska Fairbanks : with the id (1)
- University of ArkansaS : with the id (2)
- University of California, Berkeley : with the id (3)

now if the user picked "University of Alaska Fairbanks" and he pressed submit all the information for "University of Alaska Fairbanks" should appear and that's what the code will do , depends on the id of option the results will be .

Now lets get to the code : 
In my code i used PDO to connect to the database and to fetch data from the database . Whats PDO ? and how to fetch data from the database ?

> PDO is an acronym for PHP Data Objects. PDO is a lean, consistent way to access databases. This means developers can write portable code much easier. PDO is not an abstraction layer like PearDB. PDO is a more like a data access layer which uses a unified API (Application Programming Interface).

To learn how to fetch data from the database , i prefer that you read this subject : 
PHP Select Data From MySQL : http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

edit ( Thank you chris85 ): i edited the prepare statement so it can be secure from SQL injection :

Please read this : [Prepared statements and stored procedures](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Old Code :

```
$FetchUniversity = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM universities WHERE id= university ");
$FetchUniversity->execute();
```

New Code :

```
 $FetchUniversity = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM universities WHERE id= ? ");
 $FetchUniversity->execute(array($university_id));
```

full code is here :

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
  <select name="university">
    <option SELECTED>Pick University </option>
    <option value="1">University of Alaska Fairbanks</option>
    <option value="2">University of Arkansas</option>
    <option value="3">University of California, Berkeley</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
 <?php 

    $servername = "Localhost";
    $username   = "root";
    $password   = "";
    $database  = "Name of the database";

        try {
                $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
                // set the PDO error mode to exception
                $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            }
        catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
            }

        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
                $university_id = $_POST['university'];
                $FetchUniversity = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM universities WHERE id= ? ");
                $FetchUniversity->execute(array($university_id));
                $FetchUni = $FetchUniversity->FETCH(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                echo $PickerUni = $FetchUni['university_name'];
            }
        else 
            {
            echo "Please Pick a university";

            }
?>
</body>
<html>
```

I tested this code on my pc ( Local pc ) so the servername is " Localhost " .

I saw that you did not give the submit button a name , that's wrong , you should give it a name if you are not going to use something like AJAX . With the time everything will be easy for you , and again this was a test code , if it was not , you would see me putting things to protect the Query , but its a test code , so no danger .Hope this help you in the future and if something did not work with you let me know .

Comment: `id= $university_id ` is not how prepared statements should be written. They  should be parameterized. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php This is open to SQL injections as is.

Comment: @chris85 yes sir i know that , and you are right , but when i see a simple code that the the OP has small knowledge with the basics i have to show him a simple code so he can learn how the code running and then when the coder reach to the security part then yes the code should be secure , but any way i edited the code so it can be secured from SQL injections   , thank you =)

Comment: Looks good now. `reach to the security part` isn't a good way to develop. You should develop it secure from the starting point. It is more work to go back and fix it (and you might forget a part you meant to secure).

Comment: @chris85 well cant agree more , thank you sir , will take that as a great advice . = )